# If $v=U.r$, $U^H=U^{-1}\Leftrightarrow r^H.r=v^H.v$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand\dag\dagger$
The exercise is, given that $v=U.r$, prove that $U^\dag=U^{-1}\Leftrightarrow r^\dag.r=v^\dag.v$. I get the $(\Rightarrow)$ but not the $(\Leftarrow)$.

$(\Rightarrow)$

$v^\dag.v=(U.r)^\dag.(U.r)=r^\dag.U^\dag.U.r=r^\dag.U^{-1}.U.r=r^\dag.I.r=r^\dag.r$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks straightforward: 
From your formulation, it does assume $U$ is invertible (i.e., $U^{-1}$ exist).
Given $v=U r$, thus implies $r=U^{-1} v$.

Now things will fall in place, if you stretch in the standard way.
\begin{eqnarray*}
r^{*} r &=& (U^{-1} v)^{*} U^{-1} v \\
&=& v^{*} \left(U^{H}\right)^{-1}  U^{-1} v \\
&=& v^{*} \left( U U^{H}\right)^{-1}  v \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now $ v^{*} \left( U U^{H}\right)^{-1}  v =v^{*}v$ imply, $U U^{H}=\mathbb{I}$ , which means $U^{-1}=U^{H}$.

is this what you are searching for?